Conflict between sockaddr sizes and hardware interface name lengths
I have a C code to send messages via specified hardware interfaces.
Here are two fragments:
Fragment #1:
int nb;
char *msg;
struct sockaddr sap;

msg = "hello world";
nb  = strlen(msg);

memset(&sap, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
memcpy(sap.sa_data, itf, strlen(itf));

st = sendto(sck, msg, nb, 0, &sap, sizeof(struct sockaddr);
if (st == -1)
   fprintf(stderr, "sendto: %s\n", strerror(errno));

Fragment #2:
int dom, proto;
struct sockaddr_pkt sap;

proto = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
dom   = AF_PACKET;

memset(&sap, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_pkt);
sap.spkt_family   = dom;
sap.spkt_protocol = proto;
memcpy(sap.spkt_device, itf, sizeof(sap.spkt_device));

st = bind(sck, (void *) &sap, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
if (st == -1)
   fprintf(stderr, "setup_socket: bind: %s\n", strerror(errno));

Both fragments get an open socket, sck, and the interface name, itf.
With
itf = "enp3s0";

both fragments succeed (i.e. no error).
With
itf = "enx0123456789a";

both fail. The apparent cause is that the sizes of
sap.sa_data or sap.spkt_device are 14 bytes while the
length of itf is 15 bytes. Consequently, the device name gets
truncated to enx0123456789 and the bind or sendto fail saying
(quite properly) that no such device can be found.
Since these device names are made up by the system (systemd?)
what can I do about this?

Based on the info in this question what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

This issue appears to be noted under spkt_device device name truncation in the BUGS section of the packet(7) manpage - it goes on to say "The preferred solution is to rewrite code to avoid SOCK_PACKET.  Possible  user  solutions are to disable Predictable Network Interface Names or to rename the interface to a name of at most 13 bytes, for example using the ip(8) tool."
